# re arranging a series of generated divs with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a series of generated products which somewhat looks like this

```
<div class="product"><div class="productImage" title="one"></div></div>
<div class="product"><div class="productImage" title="two"></div></div>
<div class="product"><div class="productImage" title="three"></div></div>
<div class="product"><div class="productImage" title="four"></div></div>
```

Is there a way I could put them in an array to show them in different order using javascript?

Cant figure it out. Any suggestion?

```
what I have right now
<div class="product">
    <div class="productImage" title="Elixer Altima">product image goes here with other shopping features</div>
</div>
<div class="product">
    <div class="productImage" title="Bain Oleo Relax">product image goes here with other shopping features</div>
</div>
<div class="product">
    <div class="productImage" title="Satin">product image goes here with other shopping features</div>
</div>
<div class="product">
    <div class="productImage" title="Hair Cream">product image goes here with other shopping features</div>
</div>

New Order to be
<div class="product">
    <div class="productImage" title="Hair Cream">product image goes here with other shopping features</div>
</div>
<div class="product">
    <div class="productImage" title="Satin">product image goes here with other shopping features</div>
</div>
<div class="product">
    <div class="productImage" title="Bain Oleo Relax"></div>
</div>
<div class="product">
    <div class="productImage" title="Elixer Altima">product image goes here with other shopping features</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What order would you like them to appear in, or what determines the order?

Comment: can change order based on just about any part of the html...depends what you want

Comment: there is no specific order. I am trying to read the title and put them in terms of the priority. For example three, one, four, two.

Comment: @soum We need to know *how* to determine the order before we can answer. Why is three higher priority than four?

Comment: well lets say I am trying to group them together by changing the order. The title tags hold the name of the products. These products are generated and now I am trying to show them one after the other. I dont have a way to control how they show up on the page so my only option is to arrange them after they show up in the DOM. Is that possible?

Comment: @soum Yes, it is, but again we need to see your titles if we're going to tell you how to sort based upon them. So us your *actual* markup (or as close as is necessary), along with what you would like to see *after* the sorting has taken place.

Comment: @jonathan I just added a bit of code to the question. Does it make it little clear?

Comment: It looks like you just want to reverse their natural order...

Comment: @jonathan honestly there is no specific order. I was wondering if it could be more like I can see it an array where I am saying I would move the 4th item to the 2nd position because the product makes more sense next to another one.

Comment: @soum You can't have code arbitrarily order items if there is no definable logic by which the items should be ordered.

Comment: @jonathan, thats exactly what I was thinking. So that approach wont work. Maybe I gotta re think this little bit more.

Comment: @soum I would encourage you to provide the ability to declare a priority level via a `data-*` attribute, and then perform the sort based on that (unless you can sort from the server - that is always better).

Comment: @jonathan - that makes a lot of sense. This is a very good suggestion.

Comment: @soum If you decide to go that route, the first suggestion (sort alphabetically) would work largely without being changed. Just grab `.data('priority')` instead of `.text()`.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan. I took your idea of arranging it in the server and it worked great.

Answer (score 0):

I have had good luck with this http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/sorting-elements-with-jquery/

Answer (score 0):

Assume you want titles in alphabetic order .

```
var $items= $('.product').detach();

$('#container').append( $items.sort( sortTitles));


function sortTitles(a,b){
    return a.title > b.title ? 1 :-1;

}
```

Adjust sort function for other attributes as required

Comment: yes that would make sense only if I am trying to get them in any order. But in this case there cant be any standard order. That is the challenge actually. Its kinda like a business decision where the merchant decides which products displays next to what. I wish there was an order

Comment: sounds very ambiguous. If merchant decides you would need to store `priority rank` or `order rank` or whatever you want to call it. Put that in a `data-` attribute and sort it. Read them with jQuery `data()` method

Comment: That is a very interesting approach. That actually makes a lot of sense.

Comment: easy to build a UI for merchant, drag/drop. Add a db field and you would be off and running. Would also be able to sort server side from that rank

Answer (score 0):

You can sort based on the text, html, attributes and more if you like. For instnace, if you wanted to sort based on the alphabetical order of the titles themselves, the following would work (I've added a `#products` parent element for demonstration purposes):

```
$("#products .product").sort(function(a,b){
    var _a = $(a).text(), _b = $(b).text();
    return _a > _b ? 1 : -1;
})​.appendTo("#products");​​​​
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yxCWd/

In your case, it appears you just want to reverse the natural order. This could be done any number of ways. One such way would be to use the `.reverse` method on the `Array` prototype to reverse the order of a collection, and then re-append the elements to their parent:

```
var container = $("#products");
container.append(container.find(".product").get().reverse());​
```

Calling `.get` converts our collection to an array, thus giving us the ability to call `.reverse`.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yxCWd/2/